# sharing docker containers in sequential execution of Gatling Simulations

Tags: docker, containers, gatling

we have custom java code to start docker containers for Db, cache , mock server etc. when we call it from Gatling Simulation we are able to spin up containers. However, as simulation terminates containers shut down and next Simulation will need to start it again. We want to somehow start containers once and run multiple simulations sequentially and at last shut down containers.

would like to know some solution to it?

I have tried before {} to start containers, but it is within scope of a simulation.

Comment: Usually you wouldn't try to dynamically create and destroy containers while handling requests; I'd be surprised to see this as part of a performance-test framework.  Can you say a little more about when and why you need to do this, maybe including part of the Scala Gatling setup?

Comment: we like to run Gatling simulations in Jenkin pipeline for sanity check of endpoints performance.  I am extending SharedContainerConfig  of microshed framework  and overriding its startContainers() to start set of containers. This method only I am calling from Scala Gatling Setup to start containers.

Comment: I might use the [Jenkins pipeline container support](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#running-sidecar-containers) to start the containers, then run the performance test, then let Jenkins shut the containers down.

Comment: To correct last statement : calling  startContainer() from before{} hook or from Simulation class and not from Setup method of Simulation/